# Define a kind of generic variable for referencing 2 different entities

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, generics

I have some model classes with same properties (`RevisedDate` & `RevisedBy`):

```
public class Request
{
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    ...
    public DateTime RevisedDate { get; set; } <---
    public User RevisedBy { get; set; }       <---
}

public class Material
{
    public int MaterialId { get; set; }
    ...
    public DateTime RevisedDate { get; set; } <---
    public User RevisedBy { get; set; }       <---
}
```

Now I have the following code:

```
if (entry.Entity is Request)
{
    Request request = (Request)entry.Entity;
    ctx.LoadProperty(request.RevisedBy, x => x.Roles);
    if (request.RevisedBy.Roles.Find(x => x.RoleName == "ADMIN") == null) return;
}

if (entry.Entity is Material)
{
    Material material = (Material)entry.Entity;
    ctx.LoadProperty(material.RevisedBy, x => x.Roles);
    if (material.RevisedBy.Roles.Find(x => x.RoleName == "ADMIN") == null) return;
}
```

**My question:** is it possible to assemble both codes and do something generic like this:

```
if (entry.Entity is Request|| entry.Entity is Material)
{
    var myEntity = entry.Entity;
    ctx.LoadProperty(myEntity.RevisedBy, x => x.Roles);
    if (myEntity.RevisedBy.Roles.Find(x => x.RoleName == "ADMIN") == null) return;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an interface that defines the "Revisable" contract. Then make the classes implement this interface

```
public interface IRevisable
{
   DateTime RevisedDate { get; set; }
   User RevisedBy { get; set; }    
}


public class Request: IRevisable
{
}

public class Material: IRevisable
{
}
```

and then

```
if (entry.Entity is IRevisable)
{
     var myEntity = entry.Entity as IRevisable;
     ctx.LoadProperty(myEntity.RevisedBy, x => x.Roles);
     if (myEntity.RevisedBy.Roles.Find(x => x.RoleName == "ADMIN") == null)    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You definatly can inherit your classes from some kind of `BaseEntity` class:

```
public class BaseEntity 
{
    ...
    public DateTime RevisedDate { get; set; } <---
    public User RevisedBy { get; set; }       <---
}


public class Request: BaseEntity 
{
    ...
}

public class Material: BaseEntity 
{
    ...
}
```

and then you can just make it like this:

```
if (entry.Entity is BaseEntity)
{
   ... // your stuff
}
```